# Retrieving timestamp of last device shut down

Tags: android

I have an app that need to set parameters depending on time of day. It works ok if device never turns off. But if device is turned off for some time - variables takes wrong values. How can i save time in the moment of turning device of and than retrieve it on boot? My app use Servieces, Activity and BroadcastRecievers. But, as i know, no lifecycle callbacks are called during emergency turning off (when battery is depleted, for example)...

Comment: Time of day in millisecond ? second ?

Comment: Milliseconds, like Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()